# How to add a blank page and generate a menu using wagtail(nescode)?

Tags: django, wagtail

I am using the open source nescode(The open source is below).
https://github.com/nescode/wagtailcmsdemo

I know how to create default wagtail's page.
[image]

It can auto create the menu on the top bar when I select the "show in menus".
And the result is below:
[image]
But I don't know how to create a blank page. 
The blank page that I want to show highcharts figures(http://www.highcharts.com/).
What is the processure for creating the page with highcharts and add the page onto the menu?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/getting_started/tutorial.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have followed the tutorial.But I don't know how to create a new page using python code. Thanks

Comment: OK - from the tutorial, you'll know that there's a two step process: define a page type such as `BlogPage` (in Python code), and then create a page of that type (through the Wagtail admin). I assume you're talking about defining a page type, yes?

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer.

Step1:

Basically I add in a new model to demo > models.py as follows

```
class NewsPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField(“Post date”)
    search_name = “News Page”
    indexed_fields = (‘body’, )

    NewsPage.content_panels = [
    FieldPanel(‘title’, classname=”full title”),
    FieldPanel(‘date’),
    FieldPanel(‘body’, classname=”full”),
    ]
```

Step2:

./manage.py migrate

Step3:

add file news_page.html
[image]

Step4:

Finaly you can see the button that can create the news_page.
[image]